# "MyClass object = (MyClass) t.newInstance()" considered harmful

Tags: security, isv, dynamic, platform-bug

I hope this turns out to be a still unknow security flaw that will be soon fixed by Salesforce.com.

**From code in my managed package I was able to call the constructor of a packaged class of another company and by that create records in the database. By accident!**

In an internal app we need to dynamically load classes that implement a packaged interface and store an instance of them in a list. The following methods does this:

```
private static List<Rule> getAllRules() {
    List<Rule> results = new List<Rule>();

    for(ApexClass clazz : [SELECT NamespacePrefix, Name 
                           FROM ApexClass 
                           WHERE isValid = true]) {
        Type t = Type.forName(clazz.NamespacePrefix, clazz.Name);

        try {
            Rule rule = (Rule) t.newInstance();
            results.add(rule);
        }
        catch(Exception ignored) {}
    }
    return results;
}
```

I knew this loop would find other classes that cannot be instantiated. Therefore I put everything inside the try/catch.

But the default constructor of basically every class in the target org is called before. Including all harmful side-effect.

Should the platform not prevent this from happening? 
By how would I be able to call `newInstance()` only on classes that implement a certain interface?

> Adding a `if(clazz.Body.contains(' implements Rule'))` block doesn't make
>   it really safe as someone could add that text in a comment of a harmful class.

Comment: ...and the documentation recommends to do it that way: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_type.htm#apex_System_Type_newInstance

Comment: @andrewfawcett: Maybe the ToolingAPI (wrapper) would allow to find out if a class implements a certain interface.

Comment: Are you sure this code allows you to instantiate non-Global classes in other namespaces? By design you should be able to instantiate global classes in other namespaces.

Comment: @jkraybill: You are right, that global classes default constructor are i a way designed to be called by everybody. But calling it by accident as the platform does not allow some kind of filtering feels a bit like SQL Injection to me ;-)

Answer (score 4):

For many use cases the ability to create instances of classes from other managed packages is a feature not a bug. It is your code that is instantiating what could be thousands of Apex classes to find presumably a few that implement your interface and so causing the problem as a side effect.

Is there a strong reason by you can't adopt a different approach to identifying the classes such as using list custom settings to nominate specific class names? I know it is not as elegant as an automatic mechanism based on the interface, but given the nature of the platform and its lack of a reflection API your choices are limited.

Comment: Agreed that we need something like dynamic instantiation. We need it like dynamic SOQL or markup. But with that we risk XSS or SOQL injection. I would expect Salesforce to provide a countermeasure to calling unknown classes (not side-effect free) default constructor.